# Xml Serialization for list Property doesn't work when one item in the list

Tags: c#, xml

```
<TotalRecords ItineraryCount='1' >
  <Recs ItineraryNumber="1" >
    <Amount>516.6</Amount>
    <TravelTime>940</TravelTime>
    <FSegment>
      <OutProperty>
        <Segment No="1">
          <Name>Ronald</Name>
          <City>London</City>
          <Country>United Kingdom</Country>
        </Segment>
        <Segment No="2">
          <Name>Richard</Name>
          <City>
            London
          </City>
          <Country>United Kingdom</Country>
        </Segment>
      </OutProperty>
    </FSegment>
  </Recs>
</TotalRecords >
```

I am serializing xml to object of TotalRecords Class. It works fine when there are more than one segment in the OutProperty but in case of one segment it doesn't serialize into list property.

I have also tried with `[XmlArray("")]` and `[XMlArrayItem("")]` but it doesn't work. Anyone have idea?

```
public class TotalRecords
{
    public Recs recs { get; set; }
    public string ItineraryCount { get; set; }        
}

public partial class Recs
{
    public string  amountField { get; set; }
    public string  travelTimeField { get; set; }
    public FSegment fSegmentField { get; set; }
    public string itineraryNumberField { get; set; }
}

public  class FSegment
{
    public List<Segment> OutProperty {get;set;}    
}

public class Segment
{
    public string nameField { get; set; }
    public string cityField { get; set; }
    public string countryField { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: "doesn't serialize into list property" - Is that producing an error? What is that error?

Comment: Thanks Brend Linde
No, it doesn't produce any error but the list has 0 count in case when there is only one segment in outproperty.

Comment: The real code with Attributes might be helpful to see something.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the following for your Classes and their Properties:

```
[DataContract]
public class Contact
{
    [DataMember]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

*Hacking* like this helps in many cases, perhaps in your too (converting `List` to array):

```
public  class FSegment
{
    [XmlIgnore]
    public List<Segment> OutProperty {get;set;}    
    [XmlArray("OutProperty");
    public Segment[] _OutProperty
    {
        get { return OutProperty.ToArray(); }
        set { OutProperty = new List<Segment>(value); }
    } 
}
```

Comment: You're missing a close square bracket (]) on your `XmlArray` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

I am not exactly sure how your provided class definition worked previously without any XML attribute/element definitions since your variable names are not the same as the XML identifiers, meaning that the serialization wouldn't populate the properties that it couldn't find a name for.

Nether the less, the main issue here is that you are trying to put a list into a normal property.
From the XML provided, `OutProperty` is a single sub element of `FSegment` and `Segment` is an array of sub elements of `OutProperty`, but in your provided code, you tried to make `Segment` an array sub element of `FSegment`.

The correct structure of the class definition should be as follows (also including the XML definitions)

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRoot(ElementName="TotalRecords")]
public class TotalRecords
{
  [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement(ElementName="Recs")]
  public Recs recs { get; set; }
  [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "ItineraryCount")]
  public string ItineraryCount { get; set; }
}

public partial class Recs
{
  [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement(ElementName = "Amount")]
  public string amountField { get; set; }
  [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement(ElementName = "TravelTime")]
  public string travelTimeField { get; set; }
  [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement(ElementName = "FSegment")]
  public FSegment fSegmentField { get; set; }
  [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "ItineraryNumber")]
  public string itineraryNumberField { get; set; }
}

public class FSegment
{
  [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement(ElementName = "OutProperty")]
  public SegmentList OutProperty { get; set; }
}

public class SegmentList
{
  [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement(ElementName = "Segment")]
  public List<Segment> segmentField { get; set; }
}

public class Segment
{
  [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement(ElementName = "Name")]
  public string nameField { get; set; }
  [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement(ElementName = "City")]
  public string cityField { get; set; }
  [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement(ElementName = "Country")]
  public string countryField { get; set; }
  [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "No")]
  public int segmentNoField { get; set; }
}
```

Please note that in the above structure, `Segment` is a list object under the `OutProperty` object, which resides under the `FSegment` object.

Using this class structure to load your XML produces the (assumed) correct data in the created objects.

Using the XML definitions allows you to decouple the actual names of class properties from what they are called in the XML data. This allows you to changes the one or the other without affecting the other one, which is useful when you don't control the creation of the XML data.
If you don't want all the XML definitions in your code, change the names of the *classes* so that you can name your *properties* the same as what they are called in the XML file. That will allow you couple everything directly